# Gradient becoming larger and larger while implementing gradient descent

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement the gradient descent in python. The data is that of housing prices and i want to predict the house price. But the problem is that the gradient is becoming larger and larger until python cannot process it anymore.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
from numpy import genfromtxt

train_file = sys.argv[1]
dev_file = sys.argv[2]
learning = sys.argv[3]

X_train = np.genfromtxt(train_file, dtype='f', delimiter = ',', skip_header 
= 1,filling_values  = 0, usecols = 
(3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20))
y_train = np.genfromtxt(train_file, dtype='f', delimiter = ',', skip_header 
= 1,filling_values = 0, usecols = (2))

training_examples = X_train.shape[0]
total_featues = X_train.shape[1]

Wprime = np.asarray([0]*total_featues)
W = Wprime.reshape(-1,1)


k = 0
while k<total_featues :
    i=0
    temp_sum = 0
    #print(X_train[i][k])
    while i< training_examples:
        A = Wprime
        B = X_train[i]
        #print(y_train[i])
        f = abs(np.dot(A,B)-y_train[i])
        #print("this is f"+str(f))
        f = f*X_train[i][k]
        temp_sum = temp_sum + f
        i=i+1
    print("this is temp sum " + str(temp_sum))
    update = temp_sum*0.0001/training_examples
    print("this is update "+str(update))
    Wprime[k] = Wprime[k] - update
    print(Wprime)
    k = k+1
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This doesn't look like a gradient descent.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: It's completely unclear code,  *Gradient is becoming larger and larger until python cannot process it anymore* , what do you even mean by that? Are you getting a MemoryError or something?

Comment: Hey buddy, i was not actually scaling the data therefore because of repeated multiplication, the gradient was increasing drastically. The error is resolved . Thanks fr ur help